# Is there a meaning for this piece of code?

Tags: javascript

It's late in the evening here so I may not be functioning very well, but I found this piece of code and I can't seem to figure out *why* it's used like this (**NOTE**: I understand what it does, what I don't understand is the meaning behind it).

```
(function() {

    var narcissus = {
        options: {
            version: 185,
        },
        hostGlobal: this
    };
    Narcissus = narcissus;
})();
```

Self-executing anonymous functions are used to avoid pollution of the global namespace, but this code doesn't need  to introduce other variables than `Narcissus` so it could have very easily be rewritten as `Narcissus = {...};`. Some possible reasons I can think of are future-proofing of the code or implementation flaw. Is there something I fail to see?

Comment: Agree with you. Other than saying its a different style or maybe the original person had no idea about the other way you suggested.

Comment: The only valid reason might be that `this` in global scope is not valid in non-browser environments. Where as `this` inside a self-executing function is always the global host

Comment: Why there's a comma after the number and before the closing bracket anyway?

Comment: @Jose, maybe they specifically want to choke IE :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a maintainability standpoint it allows the author to later add code in a Closure scope that doesn't get leaked between the creation of `narcissus` and the assignment of `Narcissus`.  Though in this case there isn't any code there so I don't see any gains other than the `this` stuff mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The part your missing is that javascript is a case sensitive language so

```
Narcissus != narcissus;
```

He is adding `Narcissus` to the global scope by omitting the `var` keyword, or Narcissus is already available in the global scope, or `Narcissus` has already defined in the scope of where this function is being called.

Then defining it as the object `narcissus` inside the anonymous function.

I cannot tell you why he is doing this, but it seems like he might already be inside a scope where `this` is referring to an object, and he want to set the key `hostGlobal` to the global object not the currently scoped object.

That is why he is running it as an anonymous function, as they are executed in the global scope not function scope. So in his code `hostGlobal: this` is referring to the global object.

Of course he could just use `hostGlobal: window`, unless this code is also being run in non browser environments such as node.js where the global object is `global` not `window`. So he might be doing it as a very unintuitive method of achieving.

```
hostGlobal: ( global === undefined )? window : global
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `He is adding Narcissus to the global scope by omitting the var keyword, or Narcissus is already available in the global scope, or Narcissus has already defined in the scope of where this function is being called.` I know all this stuff, thanks for clearing it out anyway. The second part is quite interesting, I'll look into it

Comment: @Gabi If you want me to make any part of my answer a little clearer please ask.